# TypeError (can't cast File): Rails Carrierwave File upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I am using [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and Rails getting the following error while uploading a file.

> Started POST "/upload_client_input_file?project_id=7" for 192.168.1.101 at 2018-08-06 10:46:43 +0530
>   Processing by InputFilesController#upload_client_input_file as */*
>     Parameters: {"file"=>#, @original_filename="input.csv.part_1.1", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"input.csv.part_1.1\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">, "project_id"=>"7"}
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)
>   **TypeError (can't cast File):**
>   app/controllers/input_files_controller.rb:61:in `upload_client_input_file'

My model code:

```
class InputFile < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :project
  mount_uploader :file, AvatarUploader
end
```

My uploader code:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_whitelist
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
end
```

My Controller code:

```
def upload_client_input_file
    params.permit!
    project_id = params["project_id"]
    tempfile = params["file"].tempfile      
    file = CSV.read(tempfile)
    input_file_id = InputFile.find_or_create_by(batch_name: "Test", flag: true, project_id: project_id, file: File.open(tempfile,"r")).id
end
```